# How to use the renaming function

Tags: python

This is the error which I get:

> The system cannot find the file specified: '1.jpg' -> '0.jpg'

even through i have a file named 1.jpg in the directory.

I'm making file renaming script that renames all files in the directory given with a number that increases +1 with every file.

```
import os

def moving_script():

directory = input("Give the directory")
xlist = os.listdir(directory)
counter = 0

for files in xlist:

    os.rename(files, str(counter)+".jpg")
    counter = counter + 1

moving_script()
```

It should be renaming all files, to "0.jpg", "1.jpg" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir()` will return filenames, but will not include path. Thus when you pass `files` to `os.rename()` it's looking for it in the current working directory, not the one where they are (i.e. supplied by the user).

```
import os

def moving_script():
    directory = input("Give the directory")
    counter = -1
    for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
        old_name = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
        ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)[-1] # get the file extension
        while True:
            counter += 1
            new_name = os.path.join(directory, '{}{}'.format(counter, ext))
            if not os.path.exists(new_name):
                os.rename(old_name, new_name)
                break

moving_script()
```

note that this code detects what the file extension is. In your code you may rename a non-jpg file with .jpg extension. To avoid this you may change `os.listdir(directory)` to `glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, *.jpg'))` and it will iterate only over '*.jpg' files. Don't forget you need to import `glob` and also on Linux it's case-sensitive, so '*.jpg' will not return '*.JPG' files

EDIT: code updated to check if new file name already exists.

Comment: You didn't specify what shall happen, nor did handle this case in your code. `while` will not do in this case. I use enumerate(). switch back to using counter as in your original code and also add try/except.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
import os


def moving_script():
    directory = input("Give the directory")
    xlist = os.listdir(directory)
    counter = 0

    for files in xlist:
        os.rename(os.path.join(directory, files),
                  os.path.join(directory, str(counter)+".jpg"))
        counter = counter + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    moving_script()
```

Results:

```
~/Documents$ touch file0 file1 file2 file3 file4


ls ~/Documents/
file0  file1  file2  file3  file4


$ python renamer.py
Give the directory'/home/suser/Documents'

$ ls ~/Documents/
0.jpg  1.jpg  2.jpg  3.jpg  4.jpg
```